# Defining comma separated strings in EF and using with Linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am trying to define an EF Model containing a list or array of `<string>`. Using Add-Migration/Update-Database the field does not get added to the database table.

What I want is a field that would contain a comma-separated list of string values. There may be only a single value, or there could be 10 or more:

```
"Value1, Value2, ..."
```

I'd like to be able to use this field within my MVC5/EF6 web application as a key. For example:

```
IEnumerable<Param> params = 
    from u in _context.Params
    where u.MyValues.Contains("Value1") 
    select u;
```

I know this code is wrong, but here is what I am attempting:

```
public class Param
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string[] MyValues { get; set; }
}
```

My DbSet:

```
public DbSet<Param> Params { get; set; }
```

The MyValues field doesn't get added to the schema and there are no errors thrown. Here is the Seed():

```
context.Params.Add(c => c.Id, new Param { MyValues = new[] { "Value1, Value2" } });
```

How can I add a field that contains a comma-separated list of string values that can then be accessed/queryied?

Comment: Do you want to use an array of strings, or a comma-separated list of values? You're trying to use both right now.

Comment: @Chris Hardie, I see that I included some code unintentionally. At first I was using `IList<string> MyValues`, but apparently EF6 will not create a database field of this type. I tried `string[]` as you can see, but that didn't generate a field either. I think Pragmateek provided some hints of how I can use a string to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now EF does not support **custom conversions** (maybe **EF 7** will...) so you'll have to add some plumbing.

Here is what I typically do (there may be other better ways...):

```
private string myValuesAsString;
[Column("MyValues")]
public string MyValuesAsString
{
    get { return myValuesAsString; }
    set
    {
        myValuesAsString = value;
        myValues = value.Split(',');
    }
}

private string[] myValues;
[NotMapped]
public string[] MyValues
{
    get { return myValues; }
    set
    {
        myValues= value;
        myValuesAsString = string.Join(",", value);
    }
}
```

Not tested but you get the idea.

If you don't like the idea of adding public properties to your business entities you can:

- **inherit** from your POCO business entities
- use **internal properties** but mapping must then be done with the **fluent API**
- use **interfaces** for a perfect abstraction

Comment: You gave me a hint of how I can accomplish what I need using `[NotMapped]`. Thank you.